# Modifying a list with existing references to elements?

Tags: python, list

(if you want to skip some 2 A.M. Python science and cut to the chase, my question is summed up at the very end)

Consider the following:

```
1: animals = ['cat', 'cow', 'donkey', 'horse']  # we start with a list
2: animals_reference = animals  # make another reference and assign it to animals

3: cat = animals[0]  # refer cat to first element of animals
4: assert cat is animals[0]  # no copy occurred, still same object

5: animals[0] = animals[0].capitalize()  # change first element of list
6: assert cat is not animals[0]  # animals[0] now refers to another object
7: assert animals_reference is animals  # animals still points to the same object as before
```

My understanding was that the underlying structure of a Python list was a C array (with lots of dynamic stuff going on, but still, at the end of the day, a C array.)

What's confusing me is this: we set `cat` to refer to the first element of the list (3).  In C, that'd be referring it to the address of the first element of the array.

We then modify the first element of the list (5).

But after doing that, cat no longer refers to that object (6).  However, the list reference hasn't changed either, since in (7) we see that it has  pointed to the same object since the beginning.

This is messing with my mind because it suggests that cat now refers to something else, even though it was never reassigned.

So I performed the following experiment:

```
cat = animals[0]  # refer cat to first element of animals
assert cat is animals[0]  # no copy occurred, still same object
print("id of cat:        {}".format(hex(id(cat))))
print("id of animals[0]: {}".format(hex(id(animals[0]))))
print("id of animals[]:  {}".format(hex(id(animals))))

print("capitalizing animals[0]...")
animals[0] = animals[0].capitalize()
print("-id of cat:        {}".format(hex(id(cat))))
print("-id of animals[0]: {}".format(hex(id(animals[0]))))
print("-id of animals[]:  {}".format(hex(id(animals))))
```

With the output:

```
id of cat:         0xffdda580
id of animals[0]:  0xffdda580
id of animals[]:   0xffddc828
capitalizing animals[0]...
-id of cat:        0xffdda580  # stayed the same!
-id of animals[0]: 0xffe12d40  # changed!!
-id of animals[]:  0xffddc828
```

This has led me to believe that Python lists are not necessarily contiguous elements of memory and changes to an element will simply point to somewhere else in memory?  I mean, the address of the first element of the array is earlier in memory than the address of the array itself!

What exactly is the underlying structure that lists use that explains what I saw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to think about it:

```
1: animals = ['cat', 'cow', 'donkey', 'horse']  # we start with a list
2: animals_reference = animals  # make another reference and assign it to animals

3: cat = animals[0]  # refer cat to first element of animals
```

This does not make `cat` refer to "the first element of animals", at least not in the way you seem to mean.  It makes `cat` refer to whatever the first element of animals refers to.  In this case, that is the string "cat".  In other words, the expression `animals[0]` is itself a reference to an object.  That object is the string `cat`.  When you do `animals[0]`, you get the object that the expression `animals[0]` refers to.  When you do `cat = animals[0]`, you set `cat` to refer to that object.

There is no way to avoid "dereferencing" the value `animals[0]`.  That is, there is no way to say "give me the pointingness of `animals[0]` so that when `animals[0]` starts pointing at something else, my new variable will also point at that something else".  You can only get what `animals[0]` refers to, not its referring-ness itself.

Thus:

```
4: assert cat is animals[0]  # no copy occurred, still same object

5: animals[0] = animals[0].capitalize()  # change first element of list
```

Here you change what `animals[0]` points at.  But you set `cat` to be what `animals[0]` used to point at.  So now `cat` and `animals[0]` point at different things.  The string `"cat"` did not change (which is why your `is` test still shows the values are the same); it's just that the `animals[0]` stopped pointing at that string and started pointing at the string `"Cat"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In python, everything is an object, which means that everything is stored in the heap.

When you define

```
animals = ['cat', 'cow', 'donkey', 'horse']
```

each of the strings (`'cat'`, ...) is stored in the heap. The list `animals` holds references to each of those strings.

Assigning `cat = animals[0]`, makes `cat` hold a reference to the string 'cat' (the same reference held by `animals[0]`.

Assigning `animals[0] = animals[0].capitalize()` creates a new string (`'Cat'`) and changes the reference held by `animals[0]` to the new string. However, `cat` still holds a reference to the original object in the heap.

Answer (score -1):

The id of `cat` doesn't change because it's a reference to the first element of the *original* `animals` list. When that element is changed (by being capitalized), the id of `animals[0]` changes, but `cat` does not, because it's a reference to the *original* `animals[0]`, which is a reference to a string object containing the letters ***`cat`***, not the current `animals[0]`, which is now a reference to *another* string object containing the letters ***`Cat`***.

The list `animals` still exists, and has been modified in-place, so its id does not change. Since lists are mutable, they *can't* simply be a contiguous region of memory when originally created, as an object may be added that is larger than the preassigned block of memory.

A Python list is a dynamic object containing references to other objects (or nothing, if it's empty). If it was just a static C array, there would be no point in using Python, you'd just use C. The point of Python lists (well, one of them, anyway) is that they're *mutable* - dynamic, changeable, reorderable, stretchable, collapsible, sortable, etc.

Comment: so a list is more like an array of generic pointers to objects, rather than a container of the objects themselves? (possibly with exception to primitives or something)?

Comment: @andy There is no such thing as "primitives" in Python - **everything** is an object. The references I mentioned are kind of like pointers, kind of not. A list is an object with either nothing or other objects "inside" it - you'd have to ask a more low-level person than me exactly how it's implemented, but the end result is what I've said. It contains references to other objects that Python interprets as being "contained" in it. Their positions in memory is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Taking your C example itself -

Lets assume `A` is an array , and the array contains objects (not primitives) ,

Lets say , A is sequentially stored in addresses - `1000, 1008, 1016 , etc` , that is the first element's reference is stored in address - `1000` . Lets say the first element itself is stored in `2000`.

when you do -

```
cat = A[0]
```

You do not get the address where the address where the first element of A is stored (instead) you get the reference to the first element . That is you do not get `1000` , you get `2000` .

Now, if you change the element stored in A[0] to lets say a object in address 3000, that is you make the reference in address `1000` change to `3000` . Do you think cat's reference would change?

Comment: So in other words, a Python list is more akin to a C array of pointers, rather than a C array of the objects themselves?  Because in your example you say the array contains objects, and a C array of objects holds those objects, not pointers to them.  That's what was tripping me up.