# A list that contains itself - why resetting its element affects the 1st level?

Tags: python

This feels almost like a "Russell's paradox" waiting to happen... :-). I'm pretty sure this must be a well known issue but I didn't find a lot of discussions about this.

I'm on python3. I realize that a list can contain itself

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
s[1] = s
```

which results with

```
s
#[1, [...], 3]
```

This leads to many interesting results. Just for fun for example:

```
s in s
#True

s[1][1][1][1][1][1][1] == s
#True
```

But what puzzles me the most right now is the following:

```
id(s)
#2452848996168

id(s[1])
#2452848996168
```

OK. It's the same object. But why

```
s[1] = 5

s
#[1,5,3]

id(s)
#2452848996168
```

So if the id of `s` is unchanged, and I have just set the object with this id to 5, why didn't I got `s` to be just `5`? How did python knew to set the 2nd element in the 1st level?

Even more strange try this with

```
s[1][1][1][1] = 5
```

And you still get

```
s
#[1, 5, 3]
```

How to wrap my head around this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488199/modifying-a-list-with-existing-references-to-elements) is somewhat similar to yours although perhaps slightly different.

Comment: If `s == s[1]`, `s == s[1][1]` also has to be true. `s == (s[1])[1]` and we can replace braces content with `s` itself. As for usage of `id` - it's just memory adress of object. You can change elements in list and id won't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set the object with that ID to 5.  You set a certain element of the list to 5.  The list indices can be thought of as "labels" or "pointers" that point to objects.  In setting `s[1] = 5`, you didn't change the object `s[1]` previously referred to; you changed what `s[1]` points to.

Another way to think of it is this: initially you had `s = [1, 2, 3]`.  Now suppose you do `s[1] = 5`.  Are you "changing 2 into 5"?  No.  You are just changing `s` from thinking "my second element is this number 2" to "my second element is this number 5".  Likewise in your example, you are just changing `s` from thinking "my second element is myself" to "my second element is the number 5".

Your later example with `s[1][1][1][1] = 5` is the same thing, because `s[1][1][1]` is `s`, so anything you do to `s[1][1][1]` is the same as doing that to `s`.  This can be shown in a mathematical-style "proof":

```
s[1][1][1][1] = 5
(s[1][1][1])[1] = 5 # indexing operations group left to right
s[1] = 5 # substitute s for s[1][1][1] since they are the same
```

Comment: OK. Then what about `s[1][1][1][1][1] = 5`?

Comment: @Theguy: It is the same thing.  `s[1][1][1][1]` is the same as `s`, so adding one more `[1]` and doing `s[1][1][1][1][1] = 5` is no different than doing `s[1] = 5`.  That is, `s[1][1][1][1][1] = 5` => `(s[1][1][1][1])[1] = 5` => `s[1] = 5`.

Comment: So how about constructing an object that contains only itself and nothing else? `s = [1]` and then `s[0] = s`. Now this object has nothing inside but itself. So strange... Can I probe such object deeper? For example ,how much memory does it take?

Comment: @Theguy: It seems like you're getting into different issues than the one you originally asked in your question.  If you have questions about memory usage and "probing deeper" you might want to ask that separately.  As for the memory usage, it won't use significantly more memory than any other one-element list.  The list essentially just contains a pointer back to itself; there's no actual copying.